# Are object prototypes, in JS, basically a storage for methods and properties

Tags: javascript

I have been learning about prototypes for the past few days and I just need some clarification. Is an object's prototype basically "storage" for methods and properties so that the object itself can access these methods and properties?

Comment: Well in that sense, the object itself is also storage. The advantage of the prototype is to avoid duplication of methods and properties that are intended to be shared across objects.

Comment: Objects don't have prototypes. **Functions** have prototypes.

Comment: Well, objects are *related* to a prototype, in various ways, but the way prototypes are managed has to do with constructor functions (usually).

Comment: @Pointy they don't have an instrinsic property named `prototype`, but [they do indeed have prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes). I think saying they don't is a bit misleading. You access an object's prototype via `Object.getPrototypeOf(myObject)`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes of course I understand that, but for somebody asking basic questions about what a "prototype" is, the intricacies of how the mechanism really works in all it's weird glory may be a little overwhelming.

Comment: Also, objects don't access properties and methods. *Code* accesses properties and methods. Objects are just data.